# Debating the use of dependency injection in iOS app

Tags: dependency-injection, mono

I'm working on an iOS app where we need different binaries for each customer based on their needs. A customer may want to change all the colors, icons and texts. We can do that through white labeling process. The problem here, though, is when they ask for different behavior, for instance, removing login screen and making it optional to login.

I thought we can use dependency injections and use different handlers for each customer if needed. For instance, we can have LoginHandler1 and LoginHandler2, both implementing ILoginHandler and inherit from UIViewController.

However, use of dependency injection is costly, it slows down the app because resolving is expensive comparing to normal instantiation.

The other way is to define all these behaviors in the app and enable/disable them in a plist file. like "is login optional? yes/no"

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the entire object graph up-front, in the composition root. Object creation, and constructor injection, should not take much time at all as long as your constructors are not doing any actual work.

That being said, there are times when creating the entire object graph at the start of the application may take longer than is acceptable. In those cases, you can use [lazy-loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) to defer the costly initialization until later - *while still creating the objects in the composition root*.

Mark Seemann describes this approach in more detail here: [Compose object graphs with confidence](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/).

Answer (score 1):

> I thought we can use dependency injections and use different handlers for each customer if needed.

You thought right. Flexibility is one of the main reasons people use DI.

> However, use of dependency injection is costly, it slows down the app because resolving is expensive comparing to normal instantiation.

It really doesn't cost that much at all. Have you tried it yourself? Unless the object in question (i.e. the object being injected) is very expensive to instantiate, you have no real reason to stay away from DI and Inversion Of Control. Also, as @Lilshieste noted above, creating the object graph up front (see AppDelegate) will probably make this even less a problem.

A good way of doing that is described here:
http://cocoapatterns.com/passing-data-between-view-controllers/ and here http://cocoapatterns.com/ios-view-controller-transitions-mediator-pattern/

> The other way is to define all these behaviors in the app and enable/disable them in a plist file. like "is login optional? yes/no"

While less "elegant", this solution is a pretty useful one, especially if the project is not really big in terms of number of classes and VCs. It is also the easiest one to implement if the app code is already laid out and introducing major design changes would ask for lots of refactoring.

Always take action based on the task at hand, there is rarely if ever a single solution to a software design problem.